# Syntax error for cross domain messaging

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, messaging

below is my code. I am trying to receive data from a website using cross-domain messaging. When I click the runit button, I keep getting the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified." Please help me identify the problem, I am at a loss.

html code:

```
<html>
<script language="JavaScript">

function runit() {
    alert("here");
    // Get the iframe window object
    var client = document.getElementById('client');
    // Create the data string to be passed to the OPS JavaScript
    var data = "{'url' : 'http://ops.epo.org/3.0/rest-services/published-data/publication/epodoc/EP1000000/biblio', " + "'method' : 'GET', " + "'requestHeaders' : {'Origin': 'ops.epo.org', 'Accept': 'application/json' } " + "}";
    alert(data);
    // Use the postMessage() method in order to send the data to the
    // iframe object
    client.contentWindow.postMessage(data, 'ops.epo.org');
}
// Add event listener for your window
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
// Method handling window events
function receiveMessage(event) {
    alert("here");
    // Check origin of the event!
    if (event.origin == "http://ops.epo.org") {
        var dataJSON = eval('(' + event.data + ')');
        // work with data / display data
        alert(dataJSON);
    } 
    else {
        alert("Got message from unknown source.");
    }
}    

</script>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="runit()" value="runit"></input>
    <iframe width=100 height=100 id="client" src="http://ops.epo.org/3.0/xss/crosssitescript.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
I tried double quotes for the data string, and JSON.stringify, and it didn't work:

```
    var data = JSON.stringify('{"url" : "http://ops.epo.org/3.0/rest-services/published-data/publication/epodoc/EP1000000/biblio", ' + '"method" : "GET", ' + '"requestHeaders" : {"Origin": "ops.epo.org", "Accept": "application/json" } ' + '}');
```

Comment: It work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6zCgA/

Comment: Maybe it's because the other side is expecting valid JSON, and yours is invalid. Keys and values must use double quotes.

Comment: better is using JSON.stringify on an object.

Comment: see edits - I tried both suggestions and it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to pass the protocol of the `targetOrigin` when you call `postMessage`:

```
client.contentWindow.postMessage(data, 'http://ops.epo.org');
```

This also works, but may have security implications:

```
client.contentWindow.postMessage(data, '*');
```

I peeked at the [documentation](http://documents.epo.org/projects/babylon/eponot.nsf/0/8a3973b80c6ee4ddc125789a002dd56a/%24FILE/OPS_v2_6_2_cross-domain_requests_v1_0_0.pdf) for what you're trying to do, and there's also the option to use JSONP. Why not just use that, since it's simpler and probably better supported?

Comment: bfavaretto - points well earned. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6zCgA/1/). Also, JSONP cannot be used for all the functionality of this website.

Comment: It's really weird that the error produced by putting in the wrong origin is specifically a syntax error. And it's only a syntax error in some browser and not others.